# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: p[0] is undefined

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am trying to develop a web scraping tool. I have a python script and a javascript code.Python script calls a javascript code. My javascript code retrives the relevant content from web page. And returns this content to python script. Javascript code works fine when we manually run it on browser. 
This is my js code:

```
var doc = ""
var path1 = document.getElementsByClassName("entry-header")[0]
doc = doc + path1.innerText
doc = doc + "\n"
var path2 = document.getElementsByClassName("entry-content")[0]
var cont = path2.getElementsByTagName("p")
for (var i=0; i<cont.length; i++)
{
   doc = doc+cont[i].innerText
   doc = doc+ "\n"
}

res()

function res()
{
  return doc
}
```

And here is my python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
js = open("generalized.js", "r").read()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/branch-and-bound-set-1-       introduction-with-01-knapsack/")
result = driver.execute_script(js)
print result
```

But it gives me following error when called through python.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sample.py", line 7, in <module>
result = driver.execute_script(js)
File "/home/sagar/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 543, in execute_script
'args': converted_args})['value']
File "/home/sagar/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/home/sagar/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: p[0] is undefined
```

Please help me solve this issue. Or is there any other way for web scraping?

Comment: By the way, is that space inside the url, you are navigating to, intentional?

Answer (score 0):

You are, for some reason, starting two browsers, but executing the script in the browser with an empty page opened. This works for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

js = open("generalized.js", "r").read()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/branch-and-bound-set-1-introduction-with-01-knapsack/")

time.sleep(1)  # try to replace with an Explicit Wait
result = browser.execute_script(js)
print(result)
```

With a modified script having `return doc` at the top level:

```
var doc = "";
var path1 = document.getElementsByClassName("entry-header")[0];
doc = doc + path1.innerText;
doc = doc + "\n";
var path2 = document.getElementsByClassName("entry-content")[0];
var cont = path2.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i=0; i<cont.length; i++)
{
   doc = doc+cont[i].innerText;
   doc = doc+ "\n"
}

return doc;
```

Comment: Ok. So problem was two browser was opening and js script was executing on empty browser. I resolved that issue. Now, only one browser window is opening. But now I am getting result as None.

Comment: @SagarDeshpande are you keeping the `return doc` on the top level like in the answer?

Comment: Yes.. Is it because of DOM object is not ready when js is executed?

Comment: @SagarDeshpande ah, could be, I've added that `time.sleep(1)` there - you can at least give it more time to load but better do it using `WebDriverWait()`.